# Is there a way to integrate tests of non-INSTALLED_APPS packages & modules with django's automated testing?

Tags: python, django

I have a fairly complex django project with quite a few python packages that really have no business being in Django's INSTALLED_APPS setting.  For example, I have a utils package that is basically a set of modules containing python utility functions. I also have other non-"django app" packages in my project, e.g., image_processing, cache, etc...

Django documentation is fairly explicit that for "./manage.py test" to detect and run tests, the tests must be findable in an INSTALLED_APPS app.  I guess I could put all these packages in INSTALLED_APPS but it just feels a bit wrong. Is there any other way to add them to my automated testing?

I'll admit, I haven't been a very diligent test writer and am just now starting to repent.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. I couldn't even get them to run by putting them into INSTALLED_APPS until I made an empty "models.py"

Comment: It seems you could add a new command (to perhaps a dummy app) that would run tests for both the non-django modules and then spawn the tests for the django apps.